# How do I evaluate a multinomial classification model in R?

Tags: r, precision, h2o, auc

i am currently trying to build a muti-class prediction model to predict the letter out of 26 English alphabets. I have currently built a few models using ANN, SVM, Ensemble and nB. But i am stuck at the evaluating the accuracy of these models. Although the confusion matrix shows me the Alphabet-wise True and False predictions, I am only able to get an overall accuracy of each model. Is there a way to evaluate the model's accuracy similar to the ROC and AUC values for a Binomial Classification.
Note: I am currently running the model using the H2o package as it saves me more time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you train a model in H2O, if you simply do: `print(fit)` it will show you all the available metrics for that model type.  For multiclass, I'd recommend `h2o.mean_per_class_error()`.

R code example on the iris dataset:

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init(nthreads = -1)

data(iris)
fit <- h2o.naiveBayes(x = 1:4, 
                      y = 5, 
                      training_frame = as.h2o(iris), 
                      nfolds = 5)
```

Once you have the model, we can evaluate model performance using the `h2o.performance()` function to view all the metrics:

```
> h2o.performance(fit, xval = TRUE)
H2OMultinomialMetrics: naivebayes
** Reported on cross-validation data. **
** 5-fold cross-validation on training data (Metrics computed for combined holdout predictions) **

Cross-Validation Set Metrics: 
=====================

Extract cross-validation frame with `h2o.getFrame("iris")`
MSE: (Extract with `h2o.mse`) 0.03582724
RMSE: (Extract with `h2o.rmse`) 0.1892808
Logloss: (Extract with `h2o.logloss`) 0.1321609
Mean Per-Class Error: 0.04666667
Hit Ratio Table: Extract with `h2o.hit_ratio_table(<model>,xval = TRUE)`
=======================================================================
Top-3 Hit Ratios: 
  k hit_ratio
1 1  0.953333
2 2  1.000000
3 3  1.000000
```

Or you can look at a particular metric, like `mean_per_class_error`:

```
> h2o.mean_per_class_error(fit, xval = TRUE)
[1] 0.04666667
```

If you want to view performance on a test set, then you can do the following:

```
perf <- h2o.performance(fit, test)
h2o.mean_per_class_error(perf)
```

Comment: Thank you Erin for your quick comment. May i also know if i can purely go by the mean_per_class_error or should i also keep an eye on the AIC for the individual models to choose the best model.

Comment: I'd recommend just using `mean_per_class_error` to choose the best model.

Comment: Thanks again Erin, let me complete the models and their comparison and post it here for your review :)